# How can I import a folder of .url file bookmarks as an HTML file (into Safari)?

Tags: web, safari

I would like to import a folder of .url files into Safari, but Safari only supports an HTML file of bookmarks.  How can I make this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this TS script to take the URLs and titles of the .url files, and convert them into a bookmarks.html file.

```js
async function createHtmlFileFromDiskBookmarks() {
  const list = await fs.readdir("bookmarks_to_import");
  const urlLines = await resolveInOrder<string, string>(
    list,
    async (filename) => {
      const contents = await fs.readFile(`bookmarks_to_import/${filename}`, {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      });

      const urlLine =
        contents.split("\n").find((l) => l.startsWith("URL=")) ?? no();

      const url = urlLine.slice(4);
      const title = filename.slice(0, -4);
      return `<dt><a href="${htmlEscape(url.trim())}">${htmlEscape(title.trim())}</dt>`;
    },
  );

  const fileContent = `<title>Bookmarks</title>
<h1>Bookmarks</h1><dl><p>${urlLines.join("\n")}</p></dl>`;

  await fs.writeFile("All bookmarks.html", fileContent);
  console.log("done!");
}

// Generic helpers:

export async function resolveInOrder<V, R>(
  inputs: V[],
  callback: (element: V, index: number, previousResults: R[]) => Promise<R>,
): Promise<R[]> {
  return inputs.reduce<Promise<R[]>>(
    async (accArrPromise, val, i) => {
      const prevResults = await accArrPromise;
      const currResult = await callback(val, i, prevResults);
      return [...prevResults, currResult];
    },

    Promise.resolve([]),
  );
}

export function no(message?: string): never {
  const assertionMessage = `no() called: ${message ?? "No message"}`;
  console.error(assertionMessage);
  throw new Error(assertionMessage);
}

export function htmlEscape(str: string) {
  return str
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#39;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}
```